# Selective and existential unforgability of signature schemes

Tags: rsa, signature, diffie-hellman, provable-security

I understand that one can define EUF-CMA of a signature scheme is terms of a game where the adversary is allowed to query signatures on messages of his choosing, and at the end of the game he must output a pair (m, s) such that s is a valid signature of m, and m has not been queried before. My questions are the following:

1. How does one select selective unforgability under chosen message attack in terms of a game?
2. Are there examples of signatures which are SUF-CMA, but not EUF-CMA?

Answer (score 4):

1) In the selective unforgeability game (often also denoted universal unforgeability), the adversary is given the public key and a target message for which it needs to produce a forgery (instead of giving the adversary only the public key and letting the adversary choose the target message).

2) No, any scheme that is EUF-CMA is also SUF-CMA (this is easy to show; build an EUF-CMA adversary from any SUF-CMA one by simply running the SUF one on an arbitrarily chosen message).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Apologies, for 2) I meant the other way around (see edit)

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, that's perfectly possible. You can show how you can modify any SUF-CMA secure scheme such that it remains SUF secure, but is trivially EUF insecure. You can think about that ;) I guess I have time tomorrow to edit my answer.